# Scala: What is the easiest way to get all leaf nodes and their paths in an XML?

Tags: xml, scala, tree, traversal

I am currently implementing DFS traversal of an xml such that it goes to each leaf node and generates the path to the leaf node.

Given XML:

```
<vehicles>
  <vehicle>
    gg
  </vehicle>
  <variable>
  </variable>
</vehicles>
```

Output (Somthing like):

```
Map("gg" -> "vehicles/vehicle", "" -> "vehicles/variable")
```

It would be great if there is a library available that does this so I dont have to maintain the code.
Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The given solution didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using standard scala xml library, prints out a map of paths -> "node text"

```
import scala.xml._               
val x = <div class="content"><a></a><p><q>hello</q></p><r><p>world</p></r><s></s></div>               
var map = Map[String,String]()               
def dfs(n: Seq[Node], brc: String): Unit = 
        n.foreach(x => {
                        if(x.child.isEmpty){
                           if(x.text == ""){ 
                            map = map + (brc + x.label -> "")
                            dfs(x.child,brc)
                          }
                          else{ 
                            map = map + (brc + x.label + " " -> x.text)
                            dfs(x.child,brc)
                          }
                        } 
                        else{ 
                          val bc = brc + x.label + ">"
                          dfs(x.child,bc)
                        }
                     }
               )               

dfs(x,"")
print(map)
```

Comment: I had some really long Java code for doing this and it was refreshing to see your brief example here; I pasted some minor changes below in my answer. I'm new to scala xml so perhaps there are some things that could be improved.

Comment: my pref would be for an example that uses real names for definitions, variables, and nodes. using x, a, b, p, q, r, s, dfs, brc, n makes this unnecessarily hard to follow

Answer (score 2):

**For those that just want a function to use or a more XPath friendly solution**

I have created a repository that extends the below code and should generate correct XPaths, but am leaving the below code as is since it is relatively simple and is a good place to start for understanding the code. The [repo is on github](https://github.com/ncrncornell/XPathEnumerator).

**Answer**

Here's an implementation inspired by @Samar's answer that generates XPaths (so far without proper attribute notation), is tail-recursive, handles attributes, and doesn't use a mutable collection:

```
  /**
    * Helper function to add XPaths to a node sequence; assume a default of root nodes.
    */
  def pathifyNodes(nodes: Seq[Node], parPath: String = "/"): Seq[(Node, String)] =
    nodes.map{nn => (nn, parPath + nn.label + "/")}


  @tailrec
  final def uniqueXpaths(
    nodes: Seq[(Node, String)], pathData: List[(String, String)] = Nil
  ): List[(String, String)] = nodes match {
    case (node, currentPath) +: rest =>
      val newElementData =
        if(node.child.isEmpty) List((currentPath, node.text))
        else Nil
      val newAttributeData = node.attributes.asAttrMap.map{
        case (key, value) => (currentPath + "@" + key, value)
      }.toList
      uniqueXpaths(
        rest ++ node.child.flatMap(ns => pathifyNodes(ns, currentPath)),
        newElementData ::: newAttributeData ::: pathData
      )
    case Seq() => pathData
  }
```

Run like this:

```
    val x = <div class="content"><a></a><p><q>hello</q></p><r><p>world</p></r><s></s></div>
    val xpaOut = uniqueXpaths(pathifyNodes(x))
```

Suggestions welcome. I plan to fix attribute handling to generate proper XPaths that depend on attribute selection, and may also try to handle recursive XPaths in some sensible way, but I suspect this will greatly increase the code size so I wanted to go ahead and paste this for now.

Comment: thanks for sharing. plus 1 for the tail recursion and var elimination