# How to get Xpath of XML Node (scala)

Tags: xml, scala

In the below case,

```
 val cats = <Cats>
  <Cat>pinky
    <mute>stefie</mute>
  </Cat>
  <Dog>grey
    <mute>morgan</mute>
  </Dog>
</Cats>
```

How to get XPATH of cats->cat->mute when traverse through the Node?

Comment: Do you need your output value of mute tag ?

Comment: No, i need XPath value of mute tag!
i.e. cats\"cat"\"mute"

Comment: You need stefie  as output ? i have written an answer according the way i have understood your problem.

Comment: i need this  cats\"cat"\"mute" as output!
when i traverse through the node.

Comment: Got it. Will see. Deleting this answer as it is of no use.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767048/scala-convert-xml-to-key-value-map/48860309#48860309 ?

Comment: @ashawley No its not the same.